# How to stash only unstaged changes in Git?

Tags: git, git-stash

I would like to use this workflow:

1. Stage some changes.
2. Save the unstaged changes to the stash.
3. Do some stuff with the things in stage (build, test, etc.).
4. Commit.
5. Restore the unstaged changes.

Is there a way to do step 2?

Example:

```
git init
echo one >file
git add file
git commit
echo two >>file
git add file
echo three >>file
git stash push
test
git commit
git stash pop
```

Comment: Why not commit your changes after staging them?

Comment: IIRC --keepindex does exactly that

Comment: Because if, say, the build fails I don't want to have a commit of this. I know I can delete the commit but I'd like to do this without a commit if possible.

Comment: Sehe, thanks. I can confirm this works. Gee, I looked at the manual at http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-stash which is out of date. `man git stash` is much better.

Comment: it's --keep-index, fwiw.

Comment: this helped me learn that 'index' == staging area

Comment: There is no need to limit the stash data at `git push [-k|--keep-index]` time. Instead you can decide at apply time and use `git cherry-pick -m2 -n stash` to only pick the unstaged changes. See detailed answer.

Comment: Handy alias how to `stash only unstaged` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824325/4632019).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From Git 2.35+ (Q1 2022) you can now use the `--staged` flag ([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)) on `git stash push` to only stash the changes **in your index**.

Since your question asks the exact opposite, we have 2 choices:

1. Reverse the operation like so:

```
git stash push --staged            # Stash staged changes
git stash                          # Stash everything else
git stash pop stash@{1}            # Restore staged changes stash
```

2. Stage the changes you want to stash instead of the ones you want to keep. Now you can just run:

```
git stash push --staged
```

I got this information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70231955/1599633) on another S/O post.

Comment: Good point. I have updated [my ow answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55799184/6309), in order to reference [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70231955/6309).

Comment: Amazing! This is way more elegant than my [`git diff` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70914962/2326961).

Comment: This was a great solution! My only change was I needed to stash new files as well, so I ran `git stash --include-untracked` instead of just `git stash` for step 2.

Comment: Using a git version lower than 2.35, you can stash what you want to stash first (using `git stash` or `git stash -p {name_of_your_file}`, and then do your commit and pop your stash(es).

Comment: Changing the middle line of the first group to `git stash -u` to also stash uncommitted files is handy.  Not sure how to cleanly suggest that as a side option in your answer though.. (Inspired by [Aleysa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29863853/1048186) currently above this.)

Comment: I don't understand your second option. Isn't it just the first step of your first option, and thus incomplete at meeting the same goal?

Answer (score 451):

`git stash push` has an option [`--keep-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt---keep-index) that does exactly what you need, so run:

```
git stash push --keep-index
```

Comment: True. I keep using `save` with `git stash`. Maybe it is the programmer in me insisting on honoring the symmetry with apply/pop. :)

Comment: Note: this still stashes _all_ your changes; the only difference from regular `git stash save` is that it leaves the already-staged changes in your working copy as well. In the workflow above this would work fine since you're just applying the stash on top of a local copy that already has half of the stash's changes (which git is smart enough to ignore). But if you edit the code before re-applying the stash, you could potentially see merge conflicts when you go to apply. Fyi.

Comment: @ytpete That has bitten me so many times. I really wish there was a way for git to only stash the things you are not keeping... I often commit stuff, then do a full git stash, knowing that I can `git commit --ammend` if there are problems in what I committed.

Comment: `--amend` (rather than `--ammend`)

Comment: I used the commit, stash save, amend-commit-if-necessary, stash pop method. This is fine so long as you don't amend after a push (i.e. only push after you're happy with the final amend). I'm going to try the --keep-index option on the basis that it's easy to opt to take 'upstream' or 'stashed' changes upon merge conflict. However, a properly considered resolution is probably best. As a slight aside, I find resolving conflicts to be very much easier when 3-way conflict annotations are enabled: set the "merge.conflictstyle" configuration variable to "diff3".

Comment: I also prefer to explicitly specify `save` on a stash; that is helpful when you also want to provide a message string, which might otherwise be ambiguously interpreted by git. (Unlikely but possible.)

Comment: This solution does not work for me because of the problems described by peterflynn. It is not a good answer to the question since it still stashes the staged changes. Anybody got a better solution?

Comment: Docs seem to say that `stash save` is deprecated now: "This option is deprecated in favour of `git stash push`. It differs from "stash push" in that it cannot take pathspecs, and any non-option arguments form the message."

Comment: It does not do what the question asked. It creates a stash that contains all modifications INCLUDING the index. What it does differently is that it does not 'resets' the index. But if you reset the index yourself and then 'stash pop', the index will be brought back. The question is about creating a stash that does NOT INCLUDE indexed files.

Comment: I'm a bit frustrated. I began a long cherry-pick operation last night which involves some necessary conflict management. I didn't finish, and today I collaborated with my colleagues on an unrelated section of code (since I still had the build available and running, why not). Now i've got a bunch of unstaged changes I need to save, I don't need to commit in the course of continuing a range cherry-pick, so I want to avoid that, but I cannot stash because it would slurp up the unrelated changes i've staged. Seems like I will need to commit and hope for the best.

Comment: Follow up, i was able to get through the situation by using `git stash --patch`

Comment: @peterflynn You can use `git diff` in this scenario. Use `git diff > ~/patch` to export the changes between the staging area and working area, `git checkout` to discard the changes in the working area, do what you need to do with the staging area, then `git apply ~/patch` to restore the saved changes.

Comment: @whenov The problem with your approach is that `git checkout` won’t discard anything in the working tree after `git reset`.

Comment: @user643011 see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71150883/5469587

Comment: This did not work for me as I was in the middle of cherry-pick and needed to quickly stash some changes that shouldn't go into the commit. The command aborted the cherry-pick for some reason.

Comment: Please update this answer to mention `git-stash --staged`, which , despite sounding synonymous is quite different and much more what users expect than `git stash --keep-index`. See [The third-most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71222518/1048186) which discuss this.

Answer (score 91):

This may be done in 3 steps: save staged changes, stash everything else, restore index with staged changes. Which is basically:

```
git commit -m 'Save index'
git stash push -u -m 'Unstaged changes and untracked files'
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

This will do exactly what you want.

If you do not wish to stash untracked files, you can use

```
git commit -m 'Save index'
git stash push -m 'Unstaged changes'
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Neither version affects gitignored files.

Comment: Note: `-u` also stashes untracked files.

Comment: This approach essentially duplicates what `git stash save --keep-index` does with a lot more work. I don't see any advantages.

Comment: @vas No, the approach does not duplicate that. See peterflynn's comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: Excellent, but the purpose of stashing unstaged changes was to test staged changes *before* committing them. So there is no point in executing your third command `git reset --soft HEAD^`.

Comment: Pro tip: You can generally combine single-character flags together: `-u -m` can become `-um` e.g. `git stash push -um "Greatest stashing ever"`

Comment: Yes, this did what the op asked for and what I was looking for. The edits made in 2018 help.

Comment: @GéryOgam There's nothing wrong with making a commit if you undo making that commit *BEFORE* you push to origin.

Answer (score 38):

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

Also, Re:

> Why not commit your changes after staging them? – Shin

A: Because you should always checkin tested code :) That means, you need to run the tests with *only the changes you are about to commit*

<sub>All this apart from the fact that of course, as an experienced programmer, you have the innate urge to test and review just those changes -- only *partly* kidding</sub>

Comment: Actually this command stashes staged changes too =(

Answer (score 37):

## Stash *Without* the Staged Changes

### The Problem with `--keep-index` / `-k`

Stashing just the working tree (unstaged changes) in Git is more difficult than it should be. The accepted answer, and quite a few other answers, stashes the unstaged changes and leaves the stage alone as requested via `--keep-index`.

However what isn't obvious is that `--keep-index` also *stashes* the staged changes. **The staged changes end up in both the stage AND the stash.** This is rarely what one wants because any interim changes to the stash are likely to result in conflicts when popping the stash later.

### Alias Solution

This alias works well to stage *just* the working copy changes:

```
stash-working = "!f() { \
  git commit --quiet --no-verify -m \"temp for stash-working\" && \
  git stash push \"$@\" && \
  git reset --quiet --soft HEAD~1; }; f"
```

It commits the staged changes temporarily, creates a stash from the remaining changes (and allows additional arguments such as `--include-untracked` and `--message` to be passed as alias arguments), and then resets the temporary commit to get back the staged changes.

It is similar to @Simon Knapp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663567/430128), but with a few minor differences -- it uses `--quiet` on the temporary actions taken, and it accepts any number of parameters for the stash `push`, rather than hard-coding the `-m`, and it does add `--soft` to the final reset so that the index remains as it started. It also uses `--no-verify` on the commit to avoid changes to the working copy from pre-commit hooks (HT: @Granfalloner).

For the opposite problem of stashing just the staged changes (alias `stash-index`) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60875067/430128).

Comment: As a further improvement to this snippet, its worth to add [`--no-verify`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) option to `git commit`, otherwise implicit temporary commit might seriously mess up working directory because of pre-commit hook.

Comment: I had more luck using it as a function, not sure why but zsh choked on the above syntax: ```stash-working() {
  git commit --quiet --no-verify -m "temp for stash-working" && git stash push "$@" && git reset --quiet --soft HEAD~1;
}```

Comment: @Lotus Try copying it exactly as-is directly into the `[alias]` section of your `.gitconfig`. That way, `zsh` is not involved at all.

Answer (score 30):

**TL;DR;**
Since at git 2.35 flag was implemented: `git stash [push [-S|--staged]]`, you can do:

```
git stashu
```

after adding this alias:

```
git config --global alias.stashu '!git stash push -S; git stash; git stash pop --index stash@{1}'"
```

**Explanation:**

```
git stash push -S                  # Stash staged changes
git stash                          # Stash everything else
git stash pop --index stash@{1}    # Restore staged changes into index
```

````js
$ git config --global alias.stashu '!git stash push -S; git stash; git stash pop --index stash@{1}'

$ git diff 
```diff
diff --git a/src/js/modal.js b/src/js/modal.js
index d07c085..766e39a 100644
--- a/src/js/modal.js
+++ b/src/js/modal.js
@@ -6,10 +6,12 @@
 import "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate";
 import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
 
+staged
 const FormDataJson = require('form-data-json-convert');
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.uncheckedValue =  false;
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.skipEmpty      =  true;
 
+unstaged
 import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator';
 
 import { ajax_query } from "./common/ajax";
``` 

$ git add -p
```diff
@@ -6,7 +6,8 @@
 import "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate";
 import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
 
+staged
 const FormDataJson = require('form-data-json-convert');
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.uncheckedValue =  false;
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.skipEmpty      =  true;
``` 

(1/2) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,j,J,g,/,e,?]? y
```diff
@@ -9,7 +10,8 @@
 const FormDataJson = require('form-data-json-convert');
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.uncheckedValue =  false;
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.skipEmpty      =  true;
 
+unstaged
 import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator';
 
 import { ajax_query } from "./common/ajax";
```
(2/2) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,K,g,/,e,?]? n

$ git status
On branch dev-Modal
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
modified:   modal.js

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   modal.js

$ git diff
```diff
diff --git a/src/js/modal.js b/src/js/modal.js
index ac48408..766e39a 100644
--- a/src/js/modal.js
+++ b/src/js/modal.js
@@ -11,6 +11,7 @@ const FormDataJson = require('form-data-json-convert');
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.uncheckedValue =  false;
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.skipEmpty      =  true;
 
+unstaged
 import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator';
 
 import { ajax_query } from "./common/ajax";
``` 

$ git stashu 
Saved working directory and index state WIP on dev-Modal: 9f6e760 Imported Tabulator module
Saved working directory and index state WIP on dev-Modal: 9f6e760 Imported Tabulator module
On branch dev-Modal
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
modified:   src/js/modal.js

Dropped stash@{1} (509be8cf1afa340faf77aa6a2b8d008aa82a980a)

$ git stash show -p
```diff
diff --git a/src/js/modal.js b/src/js/modal.js
index d07c085..ed509ed 100644
--- a/src/js/modal.js
+++ b/src/js/modal.js
@@ -10,6 +10,7 @@ const FormDataJson = require('form-data-json-convert');
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.uncheckedValue =  false;
 FormDataJson.defaultOptionsToJson.skipEmpty      =  true;
 
+unstaged
 import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator';
 
 import { ajax_query } from "./common/ajax";
```

**BONUS for those who read till here. The alias to stash staged changes:
```
$ git config --global alias.stashs 'stash push -S'
```
And now you can `stash staged`:
```
git stashs
```
````

---

With `git version 2.7.4` you may use the [`--patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt---patch) option:

```
git stash save --patch
```

Then `git` will ask you to add or not your changes into stash.
And you then just answer `y` or `n`.

You can restore the working directory as you always do like:

```
git stash pop
```

or, if you want to keep saved changes in stash:

```
git stash apply
```

Comment: This is awesome. It's a little labor-intensive, but at least you can skip and add whole files.

Answer (score 25):

To add the unstagged (not added to commit) files to stash, run the following command:

```
git stash -k
```

If you want to include newly added files(which are not staged - not in green) also to the stash, do the following:

```
git stash -k -u
```

Then you can commit the staged files. After that you can get back the last stashed files using the command:

```
git stash pop
```

Comment: I think this should be accepted answer because the one accepted does not work if you have some edits that are staged and unstaged on the same file, you get `patch does not apply`.

Comment: If you modify a file after staging it, you will lose these changes when doing `git stash -k -u` followed by `git stash pop` - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73128025/how-can-i-create-a-temporary-clean-working-tree-for-running-unit-tests-in-a-gi

Comment: This does not work because it will still stash everything (BOTH staged and unstaged files).  `-k` or '--keep-index' does not prevent staged files from being added to the stash; it is merely for the convenience of leaving the stash intact after the operation (instead of removing it from the stash)

Answer (score 7):

Git doesn't have a command that stashes only your unstaged changes.

Git does, however, let you specify which files you want to stash.

```
git stash push --message 'Unstaged changes' -- app/controllers/products_controller.rb test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb
```

If you only want to stash specific changes in those files, add the `--patch` option.

```
git stash push --patch --message 'Unstaged changes' -- app/controllers/products_controller.rb test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb
```

The `--include-untracked` option lets you stash untracked files.

```
git stash push --include-untracked --message 'Untracked files' -- app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb test/controllers/widgets_controller_test.rb
```

Run `git help stash` (or `man git-stash`) for more info.

Note: If your unstaged changes are rather disoganized, [@alesguzik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29863853/242933) is probably easier.

Answer (score 5):

Extending previous answers, I sometimes have a complex set of changes staged, but wish to commit a separate change first. For example, I might have spotted a bug or otherwise incorrect code that I'd like to fix ahead of my staged changes. One possible route to take is this:

first stash everything, but leave the staged changes intact

> $ git stash save --keep-index [--include-untracked]

now stash the staged changes separately too

> $ git stash save

make changes for fix; and test; commit them:

> $ git add [--interactive] [--patch]
>
> $ git commit -m"fix..."

now restore the previously staged changes:

> $ git stash pop

resolve any conflicts, and note that if there were conflicts, git will have applied but *not* dropped that top stash entry.

(... Then commit the staged changes, and restore the stash of all the other changes, and continue ...)

Answer (score 3):

Another tip, related to the question:

When you effectively stash your unstaged changes using

> $ git stash save --keep-index

you might wish to give the stash a message, so that when you to do a `git stash list` it's more obvious what you have stashed before, especially if you follow that stash operation by further saves. For example

> $ git stash save --keep-index "changes not yet staged"

(although actually it does contain all the changes as noted in other answers).

For example, the above might be followed immediately by:

> $ git stash save "staged changes for feature X"

Beware, though, that you **can't** then use

> $ git stash apply "stash@{1}" ### ✘ doesn't quite do what you might want

to restore just the unstaged changes.

Answer (score 3):

2022: I mention in "[Stashing only staged changes in git - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70231955/6309)", Git 2.35 (Q1 2022) comes with "**[`git stash push --staged`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/44ac8fd1b4ce7598e2e5f4045dfbb6593a3f5b84/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L208-L216)**"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt--S))</sup>:

> This option is only valid for push and save commands.
>
> Stash only the changes that are currently staged.
> This is similar to basic `git commit` except the state is committed to the stash instead of current branch.

---

2019: The modern form of that command is `git stash push [--] [<pathspec>...]`, since Git 2.16+ ([`git stash save` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231547/6309))

You can combine that with a wildcard form, for example:

```
git stash push --all --keep-index ':(glob)**/*.testextension'
```

But that does not work well with Git for Windows, until Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), see [issue 2037](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2037), considering [`git stash` has been re-implemented in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318372/6309) (instead of a shell script)

See [commit 7db9302](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7db9302d7cc7affeb1d576a050407f40404bd20f) (11 Mar 2019) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
See [commit 1366c78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1366c78c239e7abb24d5b74cedf237f82125492d), [commit 7b556aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b556aa4b80ddfedb3de25e8787acd6c69d8799c) (07 Mar 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0ba1ba4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ba1ba4846aeb079b8eb1967a52917d32923a5ef), 22 Apr 2019)</sup>

> built-in `stash`: handle `:(glob)` pathspecs again
>
> When passing a list of pathspecs to, say, `git add`, we need to be
> careful to use the original form, not the parsed form of the pathspecs.
>
> This makes a difference e.g. when calling
>
> ```
> git stash -- ':(glob)**/*.txt'
> ```
>
> where the original form includes the `:(glob)` prefix while the parsed
> form does not.
>
> However, in the built-in `git stash`, we passed the parsed (i.e. incorrect) form, and `git add` would fail with the error message:
>
> ```
> fatal: pathspec '**/*.txt' did not match any files
> ```
>
> at the stage where `git stash` drops the changes from the worktree, even if `refs/stash` has been actually updated successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I use an an alias, which accepts a string to use as a message to the stash entry.

```
mystash = "!f() { git commit -m hold && git stash push -m \"$1\" && git reset HEAD^; }; f"
```

Which:

- commits everything in the index,
- stashes what is changed in the working tree (could of course add `-u` or `-a`),
- resets the last commit back to the working try (may want to use `--soft` to keep it in the index).

Comment: thanks I had some success with it with the `--soft` flag, except I added 2 twists: `git commit --allow-empty` in case nothing is staged, and a default value for the stash message `$1`. I had to add `#` to the end as well to avoid message being repeated. which gives me: `git config --global alias.save '!git commit --no-verify --allow-empty -m hold && git stash push -um "${1-unstaged}" && git reset --soft HEAD^ #'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's (in my opinion) the best solution, that does exactly what the OP has asked for. It stashes only the unstaged, tracked files – without an unnecessary commit or stashing all changed files with `--keep-index`

It lists all the unstaged, tracked changes (`git diff --name-only`) converts newlines to spaces (`| tr '\n' ' '`) and stashes all these files using `git stash push`:

```sh
git stash push $(git diff --name-only | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Comment: Simple yet working! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help @GeorgiyBukharov

Comment: I just ran this and it stashed my unstaged changes too

Comment: @Anentropic that is exactly what OP asked for – to stash unstaged changes. Was that a typo?

Comment: I think I mis-typed, it seemed to stash everything, staged too, but tbh maybe I confused that too

Comment: this will stash any file that has changes that are unstaged, which means it will also stash changes that were on the staged side of those files.

Comment: This doesn't work clean regarding the question - just filters for files (not changes) which are dirty vs index, which bogus ...

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in how the Python program `pre-commit` does it. Here is the code.
https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/3fe38dff05957f609cf7b97f471b35a8d9e0659a/pre_commit/staged_files_only.py#L50

It is functionally equivalent to something like:

```bash
git diff-index --ignore-submodules --binary --exit-code --no-color --no-ext-diff $(git write-tree) -- >stash.patch
git checkout -- .

# Do stuff now

git apply stash.patch && rm stash.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

Rethink: It is not necessary to limit the stash data to the working tree changes only, but it can be decided later at apply time to only apply the working tree changes of the stash.

Thus at stash time just do as usual:

```
git stash [-k|--keep-index]
```

At apply time do

```
git cherry-pick -m2 -n stash
```

Explanation: The `-m2` selects the changes to the 2nd parent of the stage commit, which is the stored index state. `-n|--no-commit` blocks auto-commit. `stash@{1}` would be the ref for the 2nd stash on the stack ...

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, it is currently impossible to save *only* unstaged changes in the working tree with `git stash push`, i.e. to save changes *from the index state*. This command saves *all* changes in the working tree (staged and unstaged changes), i.e. changes *from the HEAD state*, even with the option `--keep-index` which *also* sets the working tree state to the index state instead of the HEAD state (thereby creating conflicts when restoring the changes from the HEAD state with `git stash pop`). It would be very convenient if `git stash push` had an option `-U|--unstaged` for saving only unstaged changes (to me the option `--keep-index` is flawed), since it has already an option `-S|--staged` for saving only staged changes.

So for the moment you have to emulate

```
git stash push --unstaged

git stash pop
```

with a temporary file:

```
git diff >unstaged
git restore .

git apply unstaged
rm unstaged
```

Your use case is *testing before committing partial changes* and it is already in the [reference documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-Testingpartialcommits), but with the flawed option `--keep-index` which creates conflicts. Here is the version with the emulated option `-U|--unstaged`:

```
git init
echo one >file
git add file
git commit
echo two >>file
git add file
echo three >>file
git diff >unstaged
git restore .
test
git commit
git apply unstaged
rm unstaged
```

### Visualising states

For a better understanding of stashing, I think it is important to look at the states of the working tree, index and HEAD at each step. Let’s take your use case.

`git init`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |

`echo one >file`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one |  |  |

`git add file`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one |  |

`git commit`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one | one |

`echo two >>file`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one | one |
| two |  |  |

`git add file`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one | one |
| two | two |  |

`echo three >>file`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one | one |
| two | two |  |
| three |  |  |

`git diff >unstaged`

`git restore .`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one | one |
| two | two |  |

`test`

`git commit`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one | one |
| two | two | two |

`git apply unstaged`

`rm unstaged`

| working | index | HEAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | one | one |
| two | two | two |
| three |  |  |