# What's the difference between git stash save and git stash push?

Tags: git, git-stash

When should I use `git stash save` instead of `git stash push` and vice-versa?

Comment: Is `git stash push` a command? You can `show`, `list`, `drop`, `pop`/`apply` and as you mentioned, `save`. But to push a stash, I'd branch and commit and then `push` the new branch to a remote.

Comment: The documentation seems to have `git stash push` and `git stash save` as sort of the same thing, but not exactly.  It doesn't explain the difference (at least, I don't understand).  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: @benhorgen: `git stash push` is a new synonym for `git stash save` but with the options regularized. Also you can limit which paths are stashed (and hence subsequently reset), which you cannot do with `save`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`git stash save` accepts a single non-option argument — the stash message.

`git stash push` accepts the message with option `-m` and accepts a list of files to stash as arguments.

Comment: Sounds like a nice addition to Git's stashing behavior. However I don't see that supported in version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81). Any chance you know when that was introduced?

Comment: It looks like version 2.13.1 is when it was introduced.https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash/2.13.0

Comment: Would it be fair to say that `save` is left for backward compatibility, but is ultimately superseded by `push`?

Comment: @void.pointer Yes, it's finally [declared deprecated](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2512f15446149235156528dafbe75930c712b29e/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L34) in 2.16.

Comment: @void.pointer Yes.  Per commit [db37745](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db37745eef62c57e1609cbd50c6dbf9a8066f191) in the Git project: "While we
are still keeping 'git stash save' around for the time being, it's better
to point new users of 'git stash' to the more modern (and more feature
rich) interface, instead of teaching them the older version that we
might want to phase out in the future."

Answer (score 58):

Just to be clear, starting Git 2.15/2.16 (Q1 2018), `git stash save` has been deprecated in favour of `git stash push` (though `git stash save` is still available for the time being).

See [commit c0c0c82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c0c825ce19963ded30919778a23c3c85662755), [commit fd2ebf1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd2ebf14db52cc41e1cd39b1532d03cb1a702d47), [commit db37745](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db37745eef62c57e1609cbd50c6dbf9a8066f191) (22 Oct 2017) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 40f1293](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40f1293530427c315072df3f65a822e621ffe2ae), 06 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `stash`: mark "`git stash save`" deprecated in the man page
>
> '`git stash push`' fixes a historical wart in the interface of '`git stash save`'.
>   As '`git stash push`' has all functionality of '`git stash save`', with a nicer, more consistent user interface deprecate '`git stash save`'.
>
> ### `stash`: remove now superfluos help for "`stash push`"
>
> With the '`git stash save`' interface, it was easily possible for users to
>   try to add a message which would start with "`-`", which '`git stash save`'
>   would interpret as a command line argument, and fail.
>   For this case we added some extra help on how to create a stash with a message starting with "`-`".
>
> For '`stash push`', messages are passed with the `-m` flag, avoiding this potential pitfall.
>   Now only pathspecs starting with "`-`" would have to be distinguished from command line parameters by using "`-- --<pathspec>`".
>   This is fairly common in the git command line interface, and we don't try to guess what the users wanted in the other cases.
>
> Because this way of passing pathspecs is quite common in other git commands, and we don't provide any extra help there, do the same in the error message for '`git stash push`'.

---

With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the command line completion (in `contrib/`) has been taught that "`git stash save`" has been deprecated ("`git stash push`" is the preferred spelling in the new world) and does not offer it as a possible
completion candidate when "`git stash push`" can be.

See [commit df70b19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df70b190bdd2add42a906819f9d41dbf91cf0809), [commit 0eb5a4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0eb5a4f91182d8c05fdc15597273d2381b112d7f) (19 Apr 2018) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 79d92b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79d92b113cc6b61112b8856eca78b8b97bbaca6a), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `completion`: make `stash -p` and alias for `stash push -p`
>
> We define '`git stash -p`' as an alias for '`git stash push -p`' in the
>   manpage.  Do the same in the completion script, so all options that
>   can be given to '`git stash push`' are being completed when the user is
>   using '`git stash -p --<tab>`'.
>   Currently the only additional option the user will get is '`--message`', but there may be more in the future.

---

The command line completion script (in `contrib/`) tried to complete "`git stash -p`" as if it were "[`git stash push -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)", but it was too aggressive and also affected "[`git stash show -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)", which has been corrected With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020).

See [commit fffd0cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fffd0cf520718fcd0315bc5e0ee7a6d4762b96b4) (21 May 2020) by [Ville Skyttä (`scop`)](https://github.com/scop).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a8ecd01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8ecd0190d743f19d20917197f95317955354941), 09 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fffd0cf520718fcd0315bc5e0ee7a6d4762b96b4): don't override given stash subcommand with `-p`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ville Skyttä</sup>
>
> [df70b190](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df70b190bdd2add42a906819f9d41dbf91cf0809) ("`completion`: make stash -p and alias for stash push -p", 2018-04-20, Git v2.18.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79d92b113cc6b61112b8856eca78b8b97bbaca6a) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c)) wanted to make sure "`git stash -p <TAB>`" offers the same completion as "[`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) `push -p <TAB>`", but it did so by forcing the `$subcommand` to be "`push`" whenever then "`-p`" option is found on the command line.
>
> This harms any subcommand that can take the "`-p`" option --- even when the subcommand is explicitly given, e.g. "[`git stash show -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)", the code added by the change would overwrite the `$subcommand` the user gave us.
>
> Fix it by making sure that the defaulting to "`push`" happens only when there is no `$subcommand` given yet.

Answer (score 4):

The `push` command is intended to always be used over the `save` command, as it is more flexible and uses more conventional command line arguments.  The `save` command is deprecated for these reasons.

### Replacement

The `push` option was introduced in 2.13.0 in order to provide the command line arguments in a more conventional way than `save` does.

The rationale for this change was documented in the commit messages which added the command to Git:

**[f5727e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5727e26e44dbbf564034d3993d4d2f65dacd6fb):**

> Introduce a new git stash push verb in addition to git stash save.  The
> push verb is used to transition from the current command line arguments
> to a more conventional way, in which the message is given as an argument
> to the -m option.
>
> This allows us to have pathspecs at the end of the command line
> arguments like other Git commands do, so that the user can say which
> subset of paths to stash (and leave others behind).

**[c0c0c82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c0c825ce19963ded30919778a23c3c85662755):**

> With the 'git stash save' interface, it was easily possible for users to
> try to add a message which would start with "-", which 'git stash save'
> would interpret as a command line argument, and fail.  […]
>
> For 'stash push', messages are passed with the -m flag, avoiding this
> potential pitfall.  Now only pathspecs starting with "-" would have to
> be distinguished from command line parameters by using
> "-- --<pathspec>".  This is fairly common in the git command line
> interface, and we don't try to guess what the users wanted in the other
> cases.

**[fd2ebf1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd2ebf14db52cc41e1cd39b1532d03cb1a702d47):**

> 'git stash push' has all functionality of 'git stash save',
> with a nicer, more consistent user interface

### Deprecation

The `save` command was officially deprecated in the [2.16.0 release](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L34) of Git:

> "git stash save" has been deprecated in favour of "git stash push".

The deprecation of `save` is explained in its [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-save-p--patch-S--staged-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quietltmessagegt):

> **`save [-p|--patch] [-S|--staged] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-q|--quiet] [<message>]`**
> This option is deprecated in favour of **`git stash push`**. It differs from "stash push" in that it cannot take pathspec. Instead, all non-option arguments are concatenated to form the stash message.

### Short form

In addition to the standard form of the command, `push` has a short form whereby "push" is omitted from the `stash` command.  The `save` command has no such equivalent.  Per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-push-p--patch-S--staged-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--pathspec-from-fileltfilegt--pathspec-file-nul--ltpathspecgt82308203):

> For quickly making a snapshot, you can omit "push". In this mode, non-option arguments are not allowed to prevent a misspelled subcommand from making an unwanted stash entry. The two exceptions to this are `stash -p` which acts as alias for `stash push -p` and pathspec elements, which are allowed after a double hyphen `--` for disambiguation.

```
git stash
git stash -p
```

### Command comparison

From reading through the documentation, I think this should be a fairly complete comparison of the two commands:

| `push` | `save` |
| --- | --- |
| `git stash push` | `git stash save` |
| `git stash push -m <message>` | `git stash save <message>` or `git stash save -m <message>` |
| `git stash push -m <message>` (message starting with "-") | `git stash save -m <message>` |
| `git stash push [--] <pathspec>…​` | N/A (not possible) |
| `git stash push --pathspec-from-file=<file>` | N/A (not possible) |
| `git stash` | `git stash save` |
| `git stash -p` | `git stash save -p` |
| `git stash -- <pathspec>…​` | N/A (not possible) |

As shown in this comparison, the notable changes between `save` and `push` are:

- A partial stash can be created using pathspecs using `push`, but not `save`.  The pathspec can be provided either as inline arguments or by using `--`.
- The message can be provided as an inline argument with `save`, but must be provided by `-m` in `push`