# How to undo an accidental git stash pop with the same stash message?

Tags: git

I'm aware that `git` stashs are local only and the message will not be exposed to any remote party and the message is thus much less relevant than commit messages.

I don't seem to find a way to get the message which has been explicitly passed to `git stash save` or any other way to retrieve it since `git stash pop` is not recorded in `git reflog`.

I often write information into the stash message why I stashed and how far the stashed implementation is, so they're pretty valuable to me.

I'm aware the using branching has a lot of advantages over using `git stash` with almost no downsides. I'm in the transition of getting the habit of no longer using `git stash` in favor of branches, however I already lost messages and would like to clarify this once.

My `git stash pop` output looks like

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   test

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (958d4b921e7f3e8faa9fd2ecb12af13250e1f739)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [`git stash save` is now called `git stash push`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231547/6309) since Git 2.16+ (Q4 2017)

You can see the message tested in [`t/t3903-stash.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29/t/t3903-stash.sh#L798-L804), using `git stash list` (but that is *before* a `git stash pop`)

`git stash` is still a [shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69d71ec4433d21f464d83b529432856da2387bba/git-stash.sh), and you can see that, [when it creates the stash, it actually creates a commit](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69d71ec4433d21f464d83b529432856da2387bba/git-stash.sh#L182-L189):

```
    # create the stash
    if test -z "$stash_msg"
    then
        stash_msg=$(printf 'WIP on %s' "$msg")
    else
        stash_msg=$(printf 'On %s: %s' "$branch" "$stash_msg")
    fi
    w_commit=$(printf '%s\n' "$stash_msg" |
    git commit-tree $w_tree -p $b_commit -p $i_commit $untracked_commit_option) ||
die "$(gettext "Cannot record working tree state")"
```

It would then stands to reason that a `git log` is able to get back that commit message.

Comment: More precisely, a stash is at least two, sometimes three, commits; but the name `stash` points specifically to this `$w_commit` one, which is the one with the stash name. So `git log -1 stash` before dropping, or `git log -1 <hash>` after (provided the commit is not yet garbage-collected), will get you the message.

Comment: @torek agreed, now that I give the source code a closer look ;)