# Why 'Save' doesn't exist in git stash manual

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm watching the free lecture on git.
The screen shows me the help message of `git stash` (by `git stash --help`). It appears in my terminal like below:

```
git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                    [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]
                    [--] [<pathspec>...]]
```

But in the lecture, they use `save` as a substitute for `push`. My git version is 2.17.1. Was there some change in the command syntax in git stash?

Comment: `save` is deprecated. You can find it in the `OPTIONS` section.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44681952/7976758

Answer (score 1):

@ElpieKay gave the answer in his comment.

quoting `git help stash` :

> save [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-q|--quiet] []
>
> This option is deprecated in favour of git stash push. It differs from "stash push" in that it cannot take pathspecs, and any
>      non-option arguments form the message.

Answer (score 1):

I have [documented before the deprecation of `git stash save`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231547/6309), but Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) adds a clarification.

See [commit 57d8f4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57d8f4b4c71fe422ea3fe6d79d3e121426b46f5a) (10 Oct 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 376012c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/376012c91909b4ccdd16511cb3bcfc0121aa36fc), 18 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### `doc(stash)`: clarify the description of `save`
>
> The original phrasing of this paragraph made at least one person stumble over the word "from" (thinking that it was a typo and "from" was intended), and [other readers chimed in, agreeing that it was confusing](https://public-inbox.org/git/0102016b8d597569-c1f6cfdc-cb45-4428-8737-cb1bc30655d8-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com/#t):
>
> Let's rewrite that paragraph for clarity.

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/57d8f4b4c71fe422ea3fe6d79d3e121426b46f5a/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L87-L92) now  includes:

> ```
> save [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-q|--quiet] [<message>]:
> ```
>
> This option is deprecated in favour of 'git stash push'.
> It differs from "stash push" in that it cannot take pathspecs.
> **Instead, all non-option arguments are concatenated to form the stash message.**