# git merge "already up to date", although branches' code is different

Tags: git

I have two branches that I'm working on: `dev`, and `test`. I made some changes in `test`, and wanted to merge those into `dev`. However, I only wanted to merge SOME changes to `dev`, not the whole diff.

I could not cherry-pick commits, because that would have been too many.
What I did instead, was to checkout on `dev`, then merge `test` locally. I then staged and committed only the changes that I wanted to merge. The others, I discarded (which did not affect the `test` branch).

Now I am ready to merge the other changes (that I previously discarded on local `dev`, but which are still in `test`) from `test` into `dev`. When I checkout on `dev` again and then try to merge `test` into `dev`, it says *"Already up to date"*.
I checked the source code: when checking out on `test`, I see the method I've added. When switching to `dev` instead, the method is not there (because it's not merged yet). When I switch back to `test`, the changes are there again.

How is it possible that the merge does not include all changes I made?

---

**Edit**

I followed @Ôrel's advice from the comments and merged `dev → test`, then `test → dev` and now the previously discarded changes are gone from both `dev` *and* `test`. How do I restore them?

Comment: your first merge with modification is the origin of the problem. for git you already merge the same branch

Comment: I figured that. But what do I do now?

Comment: Merge dev into test, then test into dev

Comment: Just tried that – still says "already up to date".

Comment: @LinusGeffarth you can use git reflog to find an appropriate rollback point, and then checkout a new branch with that commit. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check that out.

Comment: " checkout on dev, then merge test locally. I then staged and committed only the changes that I wanted to merge.". How did commit partial changes? Git would create a merge commit when you do a `git merge`

Comment: I asked it not to commit changes upon merge. That way I could edit what is being merged in the end. (I use SourceTree, there's an option not to commit, I'm not sure what the respective git command is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I did instead, was to checkout on dev, then merge test locally. I then staged and committed only the changes that I wanted to merge.

The idea would be, after staging, and before committing, to **[stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)** the rest (the part not staged).
See "[Stashing only un-staged changes in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7650849/6309)"

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

That way, when you are "ready to merge the other changes (that I previously discarded on local `dev`, but which are still in `test`)", instead of merging again (which was already done), you [`stash pop` it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt).
That will apply all those other changes to your `dev` branch.

Comment: This worked great. Just to understand what's going on: 1) I checkout on `dev`. 2) I merge `test → dev`. 3) I stashed everything (b/c I didn't read closely on how to stash only un-staged changes ), which effectively canceled the merge (right?). 4) I applied the stash and discard all changes I did not want, but kept the stash so I can apply those later. ––– Is this correct? Or am I getting anything wrong here?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth 3) was the equivalent of a `merge --ours`: "records the merge, but do not actually merge anything, keep the destination unchanged"

Comment: @LinusGeffarth 4) is OK, the only "non-optimal" part if that, by applying the stash "later", you will apply *again* some changes that you already applied before. No big deal.

Comment: I see. My graph doesn't show a merge from `test → dev` though... Regarding 4), the changes are in the stash, but won't be applied, b/c they have already been applied earlier, right?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Part of the stash won't be applied indeed. And you don't see a merge because you cancel it with the full stash before. You can do it at any moment though with `git merge --ours`: that will record a merge between two branches without actually merging anything.

Comment: Aha, I get that now. Thanks!